# Free automatic composer, for commercial use

Tags: software

Is there free software that automatically composes music and does not place restrictions on the generated output? I need to be able to use the generated music commercially.

Comment: What do you mean, "compose" automatically? Do you want a program to generate music?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think that is actually on topic - and I'm not 100% sure such a thing actually exists in reality :-)

Comment: Oh! there are several privative software/hardware tools to do that, the music composed that way is known as self-generated. Although self-generated music sounds somewhat vague or ambiguos to me. Please see [this](http://www.medalcomposer.com/) link about Medal Composer, and [this](http://singularityhub.com/2009/10/09/music-created-by-learning-computer-getting-better/) one about EMI

Comment: Generative music should be a valid topic for AVP, and an automatic composer is a special case of generative music.

Comment: Maybe I'm making the assumption that all music has to be composed some how, so self-generated music, sounds weird to me. It's like calling music composers, music generators instead. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't Garageband's 'Magic' feature do this for you? (Assuming you have access to a Mac)

There's a guide to Automatic Composition with Magic Garageband
 [here.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/automatic-composition-with-magic-garageband-on-you.html)

There was also (back in the deep recesses of time) a program available for the Amiga, called `Super Jam`, which produced MIDI compositions.

-EDIT-
There appears to be a free, Windows version of Super Jam [here.](http://freemusicsoftware.org/619)
It's probably extremely dated but it used to work well enough for me.

Comment: Have the assets and works privative restrictions in regards to licensing?

Comment: ...I mean the derivative work

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.